# Turtlebot / Kinect - not publishing any images?

Tags: kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've built a mostly-turtlebot. After running the turtlebotbringup minimal and kinect.launch, it seems to run fine. The topics are all created, but no image data or depth data is ever published.

The turtlebot dashboard doesn't show anything amiss.

The front of the kinect is flashing it's green light.

Any clue where to look?

I tried an alternate power supply, wall power, and an alternate kinect. So it's probably not those issues.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12651/turtlebot-/-kinect---not-publishing-any-images?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, here's my answer for posterity:

It was a bug in my USB drivers in the kernel.

Running the freenect demos gave a lot of:
"Failed to submit isochronous transfer x: -1"
And dmesg informed me that usb_submit_urb was returning -28 (ENOSPC).

Switching up my kernel versions and USB drivers made everything come to life.

Thanks for the help everyone that tried, I really appreciate it.

---

Originally posted by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) with karma: 1033 on 2012-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the 12V line of the Kinect powered? The green LED will indicate that USB is powered, but if the 12V is not powered then the Kinect will not publish data.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2012-01-16**:
Do you see the IR-Laser (left-most lens when looking from front) turning on if you are subscribing to any depth-related topic?

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2012-01-16**:
Okay, the light on the USB splitter thing is one, and the device reports all three devices (Motor, Audio, Camera) via "lsusb" - things which I confirm do not happen if the 12v line is disconnected. So it must be powered. (Edit: Just tried wall power too, no help)

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2012-01-16**:
Hrm, now that you mention it, there is some *really* suspect wire on this one... I'll rebuild and report back. Do you know a way to tell, in software, when this condition occurs? I could add a warning to the ros nodes.